# Mysql select column only if a condition

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a simple query

```
SELECT 
   gruppo.*, comuni.Nome as nomecomune 
FROM 
   gruppo, comuni 
WHERE 
   (comuni.ID_Comuni = gruppo.ID_Comuni or gruppo.ID_Comuni ='0') 
   AND ID_Gruppo='3'
```

How you can understand from where cause I need to always show a row where `ID_Gruppo='3'`, but if `gruppo.ID_Comuni='0'` (so if there is not a link) I need to don't `SELECT comuni.Nome` column.

The above query works, but if there is not a link between tables (`gruppo.ID_Comuni=0`) show anyway a (random?) `comuni.Nome` value.

So, I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   gruppo.*,` 
   if(gruppo.ID_Comuni <> '0') then also select `comuni.Nome 
FROM
   gruppo, comuni 
WHERE
   (comuni.ID_Comuni = gruppo.ID_Comuni OR gruppo.ID_Comuni = '0') AND ID_Gruppo = '3'
```

I hope I have been clear, thank you for your help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: just like others have stated it's not possible BUT you can return a generic field that holds the real field's value when some condition is met or otherwise has a default value. e.g.: SELECT gruppo.*, if(gruppo.ID_Comuni<>'0', comuni.Nome, null) as Nome2 ..... hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, to write an `SELECT column ONLY IF... FROM ..`

You are also don't getting random results - you query is performing some kind of cross-join, where it joins each row from the table `comuni` to each row from table `gruppo`, where `gruppo.ID_Comuni = 0`.

If you need a "select only if.."-command, you have to write a stored procedure, or an sql-script.